# MySQL join with federated view not working

Tags: mysql, join, federated-table

I want to join a table with a view, where one table `L` is local, whereas the view `F` is a `FEDERATED` view residing on another server:

```
SELECT * FROM L LEFT JOIN F ON L.id = F.id;
```

Now the JOIN results in no hits despite the fact that there actually are many matches between the table and view. The ID field is `bigint`.

Frustrated, I created a `TEMPORARY` table `T` and dumped everything from `F` into it, thus making a local copy of `F`. Using `T` instead of `F`, the JOIN works as expected. But the process of creating `T` consumes memory and time.

What could be possible reasons for this odd MySQL behaviour?

---

Table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE `L` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `id2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`id2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and (this table is in fact a view on the remote server):

```
CREATE TABLE `F` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
   ...
  `field5` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 CONNECTION='mysql://userName:pword...';
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL NDB? What is the context?

Comment: @AlmaDo: InnoDB tables. Local server is 5.1.54-1ubuntu4, federated server is 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2.

Comment: Please, add your tables definitions

Comment: @AlmaDo: I now think I know what caused the problem. The federated table was in fact a view. Apparently JOINs on federated views don't work. I'm sorry for not discovering sooner. Thanks for your help, it helped me to investigate the matter better.

Comment: With `federated` engine, you should have table DDL in both servers - so - yes, VIEW is not applicable

Comment: @AlmaDo: I have updated my question to reflect the discovery. If you'd like to you can add a regular more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it states from definition of what [`FEDERATED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html) storage-engine is, you must have table structure definition (so, for example `.frm` files for MyISAM) on **both** servers. That is because how `FEDERATED` engine works:

[image]

Therefore, you can not use `VIEW` since it has completely different meaning and structure. So instead you should mirror your table and then you'll be able to use it in your queries.